# Hash include methods and/or nested attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is it possible to include methods or nested attributes when creating a hash similar to how you would when using `to_json`?

When using to_json I can include the published_events method and a few nested methods:

```
render :json => @venue.to_json(:include => {:published_events => {:methods => :to_param, :include => :occurrences}})
```

Is that possible to do when creating a hash of similar items?

```
@area_attractions = Venue.find(:all, :conditions => ['attraction = ? AND featured = ?', true, true], :limit => 8)

hash = { :main => @main_features, :local_hotspots => @local_hotspots, :area_attractions => @area_attractions }
```

EDIT:
I'm eventually rendering this hash out as JSON anyway:

```
render :json => hash.to_json
```

Comment: FYI, the (hash-based finders are deprecated in Rails 4](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/4_0_release_notes.html#active-record-deprecations).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The items in the hash can/will still include the methods when to_json is called

```
 render :json => hash.to_json(:methods => [:image_url, :to_param, :thumb_url])
```

Answer (score 0):

Finder methods return arrays, not hashes. Try this:

```
hash = { :main => @main_features, 
         :local_hotspots => @local_hotspots, 
         :area_attractions => Hash[*@area_attractions] }
```